# Selenium Python XPATH a table with rows and columns how to select the checkbox from col1 where name is in col2 and col5

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have a table of 6 columns and some rows.  For row 1 Col0 has a checkbox.  Col 2 has the text "Name" and col 5 has the text "CRM"
Row 2 col 2 has the text "Address" and has the text "CRM"
Row 7 col 2 has the text "Name" and col 5 has the text "ESCR" 
The pattern goes on like this with rows of date.

I would like to select the checkbox from col0 where col2 has the text "Name" and col5 has the text "CRM"

How do i do this using XPATH please?

I have a made a start and I can identify the text "CRM" from col5.  I need to get the correct row so I need to find "Name" and then go up to the checkbox.

My XPATH is:

```
//table[@id="data_configuration_variables_ct_fields_body"]/tbody/tr//td/div/span[@title="CRM" and contains(text(), "CRM")]
```

I would like to include the text "Name" in the XPATH and then include the checkbox.
I can then select the correct row.

The HTML sample is (sorry for the long HTML - i don't know how to provide it in a shorter way):

```
    <table id="data_configuration_variables_ct_fields_body" cellspacing="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
<colgroup>
<tbody>
    <tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
        <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBHG">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1130" style="outline-style:none;" tabindex="0">
                <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1131" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="linkhover" title="Name" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">Name</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1132" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="Name" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Name</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1133" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1134" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span title="CRM" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">CRM</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBBH">
            </tr>
            <tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
                <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH GJPPK2LBHG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1130" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1131" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="linkhover" title="Address" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">Address</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1132" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="Address" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Address</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1133" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1134" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="CRM" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">CRM</span>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH GJPPK2LBBH">
            </tr>
            <tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="2">
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBHG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1130" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1131" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="linkhover" title="DOB" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">DOB</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1132" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="DOB" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">DOB</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1133" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1134" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="CRM" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">CRM</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBBH">
            </tr>
            <tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="3">
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH GJPPK2LBHG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1130" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1131" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="linkhover" title="Phone" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">Phone</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1132" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="Phone" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Phone</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1133" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1134" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="" title="CRM" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">CRM</span>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH GJPPK2LBBH">
            </tr>
            <tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="4">
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBHG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1130" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1131" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="linkhover" title="Email" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">Email</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1132" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span title="Email" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Email</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1133" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1134" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="CRM" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">CRM</span>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBBH">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1135" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="DM" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">DM</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="5">
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH GJPPK2LBHG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1130" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
            <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1131" style="outline-style:none;">
                <span class="linkhover" title="ACVSEQ" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">ACVSEQ</span>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1132" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="ACVSEQ" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">ACVSEQ</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1133" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1134" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="CRM" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">CRM</span>
            </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBFH GJPPK2LBBH">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1135" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="DM" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">DM</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="6">
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBHG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1130" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1131" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="linkhover" title="Name" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;color:#00A;cursor:pointer;">Name</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1132" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="Name" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">Name</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1133" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;"/>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1134" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="ESCR" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">ESCR</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="GJPPK2LBEG GJPPK2LBGG GJPPK2LBBH">
                <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-1135" style="outline-style:none;">
                    <span class="" title="DM" style="white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;empty-cells:show;display:block;padding-right: 1px;">DM</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="7">
            <tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="8">
            <tr class="GJPPK2LBEH" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="9">
            <tr class="GJPPK2LBFG" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="10">

</tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate things (broke into multiple lines for readability):

```
//table[@id="data_configuration_variables_ct_fields_body"]
    //tr[td[2]//span = "Name" and td[5]//span = "CRM"]
        /td[1]/div/input
```

Here we are locating the `tr` elemen having a `span` with text `Name` in the second cell and `span` with text `CRM` in the fifth. After getting the appropriate row, we are locating the `input` element.

No need to go down and up the tree as @BenChand suggested.

Comment: This will work better for me because if i wanted to locate Address with the text ESCR instead of CRM, it could be in any row.

Comment: I will be passing in Name as a parameter from my python selenium script.  I could pass in Name or Address

Comment: Neat, didn't know you could query rows like this without traversing up and down the tree! Thanks

Comment: @RiazLadhani yeah, you are missing the opening `[`. This should be good: `//table[@id="data_configuration_variables_ct_fields_body"]//tr[td[2]//span="Name‌​" and td[5]//span="CRM"]/td[1]/div/input`

Comment: Great, Thanks for you help.